# jQuery automcplete: How to suggest 2 values, but select only one of them?

Tags: php, jquery, web, autocomplete

The idea is that a user can input a surname OR a corresponding id and every automplete suggestion field will look like "Surname - ID" [See this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omlm4.png), but when a user chooses any item from the list, only one value (Surname) will be chosen.

I successfully implemented the part with 2 suggested values, but when I choose one item, both Surname and ID are being chosen. What am I change to select only one value into the textbox (Surname), but leave 2 suggested values? Here is the snippet of code:

```
$select =mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM seamstress WHERE surname LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' OR seamstress_id LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%'");

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
    $data[] = $row['surname']. ' '.$row['seamstress_id'];
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: change your search term to allow for either an id or a surname, Then in your query, check if either of them retrieves a result before echoing the response

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize you array like this `$data[] = $row['surname']. ' '.$row['seamstress_id'];` using dot you concatenate the 2 values together into index 0 of the array, you need to use comma ',' to seperate between the values and put them in different indexes like this
 `$data[] = $row['surname'] , $row['seamstress_id'];`.
If in the select you want to show both surname and id in the same line but get only the surname value, you can initialize your array like this (in php)

`$data = arry(
  $row['surname'] =>  $row['surname']. ' '.$row['seamstress_id'], 
  $row['seamstress_id'] => $row['seamstress_id']
);`

You can find more examples and information [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)